# OneHotEncoding using keras.utils.to_categorical fails to convert to full length class size numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pyspark

I am working on distributed environment to trail a keras machine learning model, So I need to  distribute data across a cluster. for this purpose I am using the TensorflowOnSpark library. Below is the small chuck of code where I am stuck.

```
def generate_rdd_data(dataRDD):
    while True:
        feature_vector = []
        lbls = []
        for item in dataRDD:
            #record = item[0]
            feature_vector.append(item[0])
            lbls.append(keras.utils.to_categorical(item[1], num_classes = 14))
        features = numpy.array(feature_vector).astype('float32')
        #labels = numpy.array(lbls).astype('float32')
        return (features, labels)
```

This method works fine, but the keras OneHotEncoding conversion for labels fails. Below is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in generate_rdd_data
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This is the result of the lbls:

```
>>> lbls.take(4)
[array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32)]
```

But While I perform the same logic in a dummy method shown below, It works fine

```
def temp(data):
    no = []
    for item in data:
            no.append(keras.utils.to_categorical(item, num_classes = 15))
    return no
```

The Input for the temp method is

```
a = [14,13,2,5,1,0]
```

Output is as expected

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Adding extra Information that. For the first method the Input is a rdd zipped with dataset and its corresponding labels.

Example of rdd looks in such way:

```
[([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], 12.0)]
```

As you can see the rdd has two parts, One is feature_vector and the second one is label, So the first method features and labels in numpy format.

Comment: what while true for? and first code's num_classes=14 is it ok?

Comment: you can Ignore While true, Also the number of classes specified 14 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

this `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` error caused by trying to convert non-multidimetional array shapped list to array

maybe you have list like this `[2,[3,4]]` or you have string and int object `[1,2,"r"]`

and for the function dont need to convert one by one:

```
def generate_rdd_data(dataRDD):
    return dataRDD,keras.utils.to_categorical(dataRDD,num_classes=14)
```